# Creating an API pull for Vue.js

Tags: api, vue.js

I have no idea what I am getting wrong or why this is not working, I am just trying to get the photos of random dogs api to work and it is not working. See code below.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async getData() {
      try {
        let response = await fetch ("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
        this.posts = await response.json();
      } catch (error){
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *"it is not working"* is not a proper problem description.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call your `getData` function. One possible solution is, you can call your `getData` function in `mounted` lifecycle hook. Here is a vue playground [link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script >
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
    };
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getData();
  },
  methods: {
    async getData() {
      try {
        let response = await fetch ("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
        this.posts = await response.json();
      } catch (error){
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
};

</script>

<template>
  <img :src="posts.message" alt="img">
</template>
```